# Implementing listeners for Views from different layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ViewPager for the user to swipe between two layouts. My Activity's layout is the one containing the viewPager and I have two additional xml the ones that describe the layout of the screens that are to be swiped. My question is how can I  implement the listeners of the buttons of these two layouts in my activity, the one containing  the the viewPager. I'll also post the code I've written so far:

main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fonto1" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/grammi" />


<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aristerovelos2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/aristerovelos3"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>    

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deksivelos1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/deksivelos3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

first layout to be swiped in the viewPager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/galika"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gallika" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/germanika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/germanika" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ellinika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ellinika" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/agglika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/agglika" />
```

The second is something like that, won't need posting it.

This is how I've tried setting my listeners but it won't work.

```
    final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    final View panel = factory.inflate(R.layout.first_panel, null);
    iv = (ImageView) panel.findViewById(R.id.el);
```

and then I set its listener which is trivial though it won't work properly

Comment: Does your ViewPager contain fragments or layouts?

Comment: I have layouts should i upload the code too?

Comment: So what is your problem setting listeners? Of course you would have to check for nullity every time but besides that it should be the same as any other layout

Comment: Well i have set the listeners but the won't work, i'll edit it to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm really sorry, I was really absent-minded I re-inflated another layout, not the one that was on the ViewPager that's why i was getting the button events I will post my way of making it work, just in case

```
            @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            int resId = 0;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.first_panel;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.second_panel;
                break;
            }
            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);

            if(resId==R.layout.first_panel)
                ibellinika = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ellinika);


            ibellinika.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
                    progressBar.setMessage("Transfering Data ...");


                }
            });

            return view;  




        }
```